# Where can you find the Microsoft C++ Redistributable: Change Log / Bug Fixes

Tags: visual-c++, redistributable, vcredist

### Background

Prior to release, we are required to review the *Change Log* / *Bug Fixes* for all third-party dependencies.

### Question

Do you know where I can find the: *Microsoft's Visual C++ Redistributes* change log?

- Visual Studio has [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes), but this does not specifically reference the *C++ Redistributable*.
- The [Distributed Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/redistribution) sub-section does mention *Visual C++ Runtime Files*, but I don't see a change log.

Any input you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

### Related Resources

- [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

  - Can download redistributable? Yes
  - Has change logs? NO
- [Visual Studio Subscriptions](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=C++) downloads

  - Can download redistributable? Yes
  - Has change logs? NO
- [Microsoft Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/topics/cppcompiler.html) bug list

  - If you really want to get down in the weeds, this website is an option... but be prepared to spend a lot of time looking. I personally find that the search engine for this website is not great.

Comment: did you ever find it?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Nothing useful.